# Select all records from relationship table as array based on primary key of "parent" table

Tags: mysql

I have these tables:

Users:

```
+----+--------+
| Id |  Name  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Name 1 |
|  2 | Name 2 |
+----+--------+
```

Document group:

```
+----+-----------------+
| Id |       Name      |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | Document name 1 |
|  2 | Document name 2 |
|  3 | Document name 3 |
+----+-----------------+
```

Users documents group:

```
+----+---------+--------------+
| Id | User_id |  Document_id |
+----+---------+--------------+
|  1 |       1 |            1 |
|  2 |       1 |            2 |
|  3 |       2 |            2 |
|  4 |       1 |            3 |
+----+---------+--------------+
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
result = [
    1, "Name 1", ["Document name 1", "Document name 2", "Document name 3"]
    2, "Name 2", ["Document name 2"]
]
```

Problem is that I even don't know how to start ...

Currently, I am parsing a lot of data on backend side and grouping/mapping there(using PHP) but the problem that I have is that with a large dataset, it takes a lot of time (around 10 seconds)...

Is there way to create query like this in MySQL?

Comment: MySQL will only generate data in a tablular form for you. You will need to use some application code (arrays processing) to generate result in the form you need

Comment: Not sure what results you want it looks like a multiple dimensional (PHP) array..

Comment: Also, Hint: Look at `INNER JOIN` between these tables to get your data

Comment: Try using the `GROUP_CONCAT` function.

Comment: "MySQL will only generate data in a tablular form for you" @MadhurBhaiya  Not completly true.. I used MySQL before to generate "complex" data structures like JSON or XML within a table column.. You could even generate a PHP serialized array from MySQL if you want and know the structure.

Comment: by the way i assume the result should be `$result = [
      [1, "Name 1", ["Document name 1", "Document name 2", "Document name 3"]]
    , [2, "Name 2", ["Document name 2"]]
];` instead?

Comment: @RaymondNijland oh. that is correct. I will update my post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
select 
    group_concat(concat(users.id, ',', concat('\"',users.name,'\"'), ',',  
concat('[',all_documents,']')), ';') 
    as final_result
from users
join 
    (
        select group_concat(concat('\"',documents.name,'\"')) 
        as all_documents,users.id
        from users_documents, users, documents
        where documents.id=users_documents.document_id and 
        users.id=users_documents.user_id
        group by users.id
    ) temp1 on users.id = temp1.id
```